# DVOM nonstop auto ranging resistance on 1 pin of potentiometer

Tags: resistance, multimeter, potentiometer

I think this is a newbie question, but I was trying to measure a couple of pots with my new meter, and on one set of measurements (one set of pins) I'm just getting a nonstop auto ranging all over the place. What's going on here?

Comment: (1) Please add make, model and a link to the meter user manual. (2) What value was the pot, which pins were you measuring and what was the wiper position (%)? (3) If your meter has a range select button can you get a stable reading? Add the information into the question - not buried in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that your pot is dirty or the slider is not making good contact. Exactly which pins are you measuring? Exactly how are you connecting the meter leads...by squeezing the probe tips with your fingers?